# Customize footer content of main report for subreport pages in RDLC

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc, ssrs-2012, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I have one report which contains a subreport in it. want to customize footer content for subreport only.

for eg: footer is
[image]

now i have to use same footer but with a bit change in that
[image]

how to achieve this, because i do not found anything for identifying, where subreport ends.

can anyone please help, how to implement this.?

Answer (score 1):

The footer for the sub report will not be rendered only the main report's footer shows up.As a workaround , you can try following steps .

1. Add a rectangle before the subreport and set a page break in rectangle with "page break after" property.
2. In the "PageName" property of rectangle set the name of the report
3. In your footer set the value of text box with a conditional expression

   ```
   =IIF(Globals!PageName="<value of pagename property>,"<show the text you want to display>","")
   ```
  3.